# Error while retrieving a record from database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, pdo

I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm trying to get data from database but I'm having the following error
"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpExamPrep\studentDB.php on line 22"
I'm sorry I have to include all the codes, its just to help you help me. Thanks
I have the following classes

```
class database 
{
    private static $dsn = 'mysql:local=localhost;dbname=test1';
    private static $username ='me';
    private static $password ='me';
    public static $db;

    private function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public static function  dataConnect()
    {
        if(isset(self::$db))
        {
           try
           {
               self::$db = new PDO(self::$dsn, self::$username, self::$password);

           }
           catch(PDOException $e)
           {
                $error_message = $e->getMessage();
                include 'database_error.php';
                exit();
           }
        }
           return self::$db;
      }
   }


   class studentDB 
   {


       public static function getAllRecords()
       {
           require  'database.php';
           $query = 'select * from student';

           $db = database::dataConnect();
           $result = $db->query($query); //This part is giving error
           $students = array();

           foreach($result as $row)
           {
              $stud = new student($row['firstname'],$row['lastname']);
              $stud->setID($row['id']);
              $students[]=$stud;
           }

              return $students;
        }
     }

    <?php
        include 'studentDB.php';
        $stx =studentDB::getAllRecords();

        foreach ($stx as $r)
        {
            echo $r->getFirstName().' '.$r->getLastName().' '.$r->getID();
        }
    ?>

when I changed if(isset(self::$db)) to if(!isset(self::$db)), the error becomes
```

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpExamPrep\studentDB.php on line 25"

Comment: Is that your entire file? The error says something about a fatal error calling a function `query()` but I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: in dataConnect function try to change `if(isset(...))` to `if(!isset(...))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
if(isset(self::$db))
```

must be changed in

```
if ( ! isset(self::$db) )
```

as you want to set `self::$db` if it's not set already and not the opposite.

From the code fragment that you posted in fact, it looks like this call

```
$db = database::dataConnect();
```

is returning a null reference to `$db` and therefore you cannot call `query` on a null reference.

Comment: when I changed if(isset(self::$db)) to if(!isset(self::$db)), error becomes "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpExamPrep\studentDB.php on line 25"

Comment: Check if $result is FALSE: in that case there was a failure in the query. Read through this page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php, to understand how to get errors from queries.